# How to obtain PubKeyHash from Address ShelleyAddr

Tags: address, api, public-key, bech32

Is there a way to do this programmatically? I have an

`Address ShelleyAddr`

obtained from

`deserialiseFromBech32 AsShelleyAddress`

and need its

`Plutus.V1.Ledger.Crypto.PubKeyHash`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is now the function `shelleyPayAddrToPlutusPubKHash` in `cardano-api` which returns `Maybe PubKeyHash` because in the case of a script credential there is no corresponding public key hash.

Comment: I cannot find `shelleyPayAddrToPlutusPubKHash`. How exactly do I import it?

Comment: In `cabal.project`, what tag hash do I use for `source-repository-package
  type: git
  location: https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node.git` ?

Answer (score 1):

This compiles with a recent version of `cardano-node` and `plutus`:

```
import Plutus.V1.Ledger.Api (PubKeyHash)
import Cardano.Ledger.Alonzo.TxInfo (transKeyHash)
import Cardano.Api (ShelleyAddr)
import Cardano.Api.Shelley (Address (ShelleyAddress))   
import Cardano.Ledger.Shelley.API (Credential (KeyHashObj, ScriptHashObj))

                                                                                             
addrToPkh :: Address ShelleyAddr -> PubKeyHash
addrToPkh (ShelleyAddress net (ScriptHashObj sh) sr) = transKeyHash sh
addrToPkh (ShelleyAddress net (KeyHashObj kh) sr) = transKeyHash kh
```

Comment: Is there such a thing as an `AlonzoAddr` (via `deserialiseFromBech32 AsAlonzoAddress`)? I am only using `ShellyAddr` because that's what I found in the API.

Comment: `cabal build` is giving me: _unknown package: `cardano-ledger-shelley`_. Not sure what to do.

Comment: @Kwaggy: `AlonzoAddr` is fine and to make it compile you need to add `cardano-ledger-shelley` to your code's `.cabal` file in the `build-depends` section and maybe ensure you are having the `https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-ledger-specs` as a `source-repository-package` in `cabal.project` (depends a bit on your workflow).

Comment: @Sebastian Nagel: Where do I find `AlonzoAddr`?

Comment: @insitu: For _recent version of cardano-node_, I downloaded pre-compiled executable from https://docs.cardano.org/getting-started/installing-the-cardano-node and parked the unzipped in my root dir. How do I teach `cabal` about it, such that `.cabal` file is happy with having `cardano-ledger-shelley` in its `build-depends` section?

Comment: @Kwaggy: There is no `AlonzoAddr` as far as I know. You might expect one as you read `ShelleyAddr`, but in fact the "alonzo era is a shelley era", so `ShelleyAddr` is just fine.
To get the `cardano-ledger-shelley` you do not need the pre-compiled executable, but need to adapt the `cabal.project` file, e.g. like this https://github.com/input-output-hk/hydra-poc/blob/master/cabal.project#L85-L112 -> `cardano-ledger-shelley` is in the `eras/shelley/impl` directory of the ledger specs repo. You can also ask in the `#ask-hydra` channel on the IOG Discord for more help: https://discord.gg/y5kfwHtm

Comment: @SebastianNagel: I am running into `cabal build` error: _Failed to build plutus-chain-index-0.1.0.0._, and `cabal clean` does not help.

Comment: @SebastianNagel: Please see https://gist.github.com/paul-outlaw/130764aa1da5cb2c93c5be3c550a19e6

Comment: @Kwaggy Sorry, I do not really understand your question: Cabal dependencies require source code, either from a package or from a git repository. BTW, I have commented your gist, seems like your SHA1 are not correctly set which would explain the compilation error you see.